# Violation of Independence of Observations - Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, independence

Apologies if this seems a basic question but I can't find enough detailed information about what exactly constitutes a violation of independent observations.

The regression I'm wanting to run is based on the following: I have some eye-tracking data in which I code a 0 or 1 if the participant's eyes fell in a particular area of the screen for each frame of a video I'm playing. I'm trying to evaluate if heart rate and pupil size are able to predict whether or not their eyes will be in the area of interest.

My problem is that for each participant I have 21600 data points (at most, this number can vary as due to the population I'm working with there are some missing data chunks). Is it appropriate to put all my participants' data into 1 big dataset for the regression, or does having multiple samples from the same participant violate the assumption of independent observations?

If it does violate this, then what are my options? I could condense everyone's data down to a single proportion of time spent in the area of interest alongside mean heart rate and pupil size, but this will only leave me with 15 samples in total which I don't think is enough to really run a regression on? Alternately, I could run an independent regression for each participant, but I would like to be able to condense it into a group level analysis if I can.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you really trying to determine eye-tracking location from heart rate and pupil size, or the other way around?  What is your theory linking these variables?

Comment: The theory is that when they are looking toward an area of interest (in this case the face of a cartoon character) then we should see corresponding changes in their pupil size and heart rate as they are moving from a neutral state to a state of attention.

Comment: It seems to me you might have lost a lot of information by reducing these data to a binary response: have you considered modeling, say, the *distance* from the gaze point to the target area or even viewing the coordinates of the gaze point as a bivariate response?  Regardless, you might find time series methods to be useful for conceptualizing and even modeling the strong serial correlation that must exist among the responses.

Comment: One might say you have *repeated measures* or observations *nested* within individual persons and thus potentially suitable for *multi-level* or *hierarchical* models.

Comment: @whuber - I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by gaze point here? I'm new to eye tracking so I apologise if this is common parlance in the area. The task is a free form one, simply watching a cartoon while we track their gaze. As such, the AOI moves around the screen (following the characters face).

Comment: @rolando2 So you are saying that after grouping all my data together, "participant" will become a new level of predictor variable with each participant becoming a new predictor at this level?

Comment: I understand your underlying study to be collecting data like those illustrated at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2711.

Comment: @whuber Something similar perhaps, though our AOIs our not static and over the course of the video will likely travel across the whole screen. Right now I take a median of the eye-tracking samples for each frame (the frame rate is 30 fps and the sampling rate is 300 hz), by your method I would not do this, and plot all 300 samples per frame and treat each frame like another "sequence" in the example you linked too?

Comment: One thing you might consider--I don't know enough about your situation to recommend this--is representing each eye position as a vector relative to some otherwise moving target or "AOI."  That would reduce the problem to the subproblems of (1) tracking this vector and (2) analyzing the association between this vector and the position of the target.  Possibly the two would be nearly independent, thereby simplifying the problem to (1).